# как убрать похожие в массиве HEX цвета? Сравнивая процент схожести

Tags: php, массивы, hex

Есть массив цветов в формате HEX

```
Array
(
[0] => e2a868
[1] => e7ab77
[2] => c99971
[3] => ce996d
[4] => f1ceae
[5] => dec7a7
[6] => e8cba3
[7] => eabe99
[8] => ecc9a9
[9] => dfbe9d
[10] => e9cfb4
[11] => 934c2e
[12] => dbb48d
[13] => f7d0a7
[14] => d19765
[15] => ddad85
[16] => ce8e51
[17] => ba6f38
[18] => f6d2ae
[19] => 4c2715
[20] => d3dad3
[21] => f3cea2
[22] => ebbc8e
[23] => d3a478
[24] => c08f66
[25] => d3c3b3
[26] => b7aea7
[27] => c59d62
[28] => ebbb93
[29] => e8cba9
[30] => 99481d
[31] => c28244
[32] => de9763
[33] => dda97a
[34] => e09e62
[35] => dfa46a
[36] => e4b78d
[37] => 96471c
[38] => db9b5b
[39] => e2a670
[40] => a66235
)
```

И функция которая сравнивает два цвета друг с другом и выдает процент схожести.

```
function hexToRgb($color) {
    // проверяем наличие # в начале, если есть, то отрезаем ее
    if ($color[0] == '#') {
        $color = substr($color, 1);
    }

    // разбираем строку на массив
    if (strlen($color) == 6) { // если hex цвет в полной форме - 6 символов
        list($red, $green, $blue) = array(
            $color[0] . $color[1],
            $color[2] . $color[3],
            $color[4] . $color[5]
        );
    } elseif (strlen($cvet) == 3) { // если hex цвет в сокращенной форме - 3 символа
        list($red, $green, $blue) = array(
            $color[0]. $color[0],
            $color[1]. $color[1],
            $color[2]. $color[2]
        );
    }else{
        return false; 
    }

    // переводим шестнадцатиричные числа в десятичные
    $red = hexdec($red); 
    $green = hexdec($green);
    $blue = hexdec($blue);

    // вернем результат
    return array(
        'red' => $red, 
        'green' => $green, 
        'blue' => $blue
    );
}

function Color_Matcher_Tool($c1 = '', $c2 = '')
{
    if($c1 == '' || $c2 == '')
    {
        return false;
    }
    $c1 = hexToRgb($c1);
    $c2 = hexToRgb($c2);


    $diffRed = abs($c1['red'] - $c2['red']);
    $diffGreen = abs($c1['green'] - $c2['green']);
    $diffBlue = abs($c1['blue'] - $c2['blue']);

    $pctDiffRed   = floatval($diffRed / 255);
    $pctDiffGreen = floatval($diffGreen / 255);
    $pctDiffBlue   = floatval($diffBlue  / 255);

    return 100 - ( floor( ($pctDiffRed + $pctDiffGreen + $pctDiffBlue) / 3 * 100) );
}
```

Задавая себе этот вопрос, я сказал, да легко, а не тут то было, начал кипеть по страшному.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так наверное -

```
$count = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++ ) {
    for($k = $i+1; $k<$count; $k++) {
        if(Color_Matcher_Tool($array[$i],$array[$k])>80) {
             unset($array[$k]);
        }
    }
    $array = array_values($array);
    $count = count($array);
}
```

Comment: множественный notice Undefined offset, слаб я в вложенных циклах.

Comment: Да, я не прав. Ключи массива не будут пересчитываться. Надо что то другое придумать.

Comment: Поправил ответ. Так работать будет, но я не уверен, что это самый оптитальный вариант.

Answer (score 4):

Я дам скорее не ответ, а просто небольшую теорию по теме сравнения цветов и постараюсь показать какие у вас проблемы в алгоритме и почему определять цвета не так просто...

**1)** Если алгоритм на вход принимает 2 цвета `A` и `B`, то вне зависимости от последовательности подачи аргументов, результат должен быть одинаковый - тут все хорошо, претензий нет, просто для справки.

**2)** Подход к сравнению цветов по `RGB` в корне не правильный, дело в том, что `RGB` можно представить в виде 3-ех мерного пространства, где каждая плоскость - цвет. Для наглядности посмотрите на изображение:

[image: RGB]

Ваш алгоритм берет за параметр сравнения - дальность двух точек друг от друга (по цветам определяем их `rgb`, строим эти 2 точки на пространстве, соединяем их прямой линией и смотрим на длину этой линии - вот ваш критерий). Это очень не справедливый параметр схожести который не работает на практике.

**Например** для группы цветов `Красный-Пурпурный` будет такой-же коэффициент как на `Красный-Черный`, `Красный-Желтый`, в вашем случае `67`, но визуально мы видим, что `Красный-Пурпурный` схожи сильнее чем `Красный-Черный`. Такое справедливо для всех точек. на рисунке.

Сверху могу сказать, что к оттенкам этих цветов действует точно такое-же правило, давайте посмотрим на эти 2 пары:

[image: Пример]

Их `RGB` представление: `[127, 0, 127], [127, 127, 127]`  -  `[127, 0, 127], [90, 0, 157]`

Какие 2 цвета более схожи? Вроде группа 2, но нет, по вашему алгоритму будет `84 - 75`, т.е. первая группа имеет более схожие цвета, чем вторая.

**3)** Я не смогу подсказать вам точно более правильные и грамотные алгоритмы для сравнения, вам придется погуглить самому, но на память, есть более точная [цветовая модель - HSV (Википедия)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_(%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)) и [цветовая модель - HSL (Википедия)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL).

---

**P.S.** Я написал пост просто чтобы автор обратил на это внимание, если он пишет какой-то серьезный проект и ему нужно адекватное сравнение цветов